# iOS double tap zooms out, even with user-scalable=no

Tags: html, ios, zooming, viewport

I've set the following meta tag on my website:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

And it works for all android devices. On iOS however, it disables pinch zoom fully and the double tap zoom in. Unfortunately, **it zooms out on double tap**.

Any way to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

Time showed that it is very bad practice to set `user-scalable=no`. So if anybody is looking to prevent user zooming: **Don't do it!**